# How fast can Spock read?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, spock

In "Obsession," Spock tells Dr. McCoy that "fortunately, I read somewhat faster (than you)." Is there any evidence, in-universe, of how fast Spock can read? McCoy doesn't doubt Spock, and being a Vulcan, it seems safe to assume that he can read faster than most other known humanoids. Obviously he can't read anywhere near as fast as Data, though.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is Star Trek 4, where he was dealing with 3 screens simultaneously, but questions were also read out loud.  Still, it did seem that he read each screen quickly and absorbed the information before the question was asked.

Comment: Somewhat faster than you.

Comment: Actually, I'm part android, so I doubt it.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - Acually Data is Android. I think Spock is iOS.

Comment: @HamSandwich Pfff, 21st century android. It's a miracle you can read at all.

Answer (score 2):

In TOS episode 'Where No Man Has Gone Before', the mutating Gary Mitchell has a reading speed beyond any humans (and implicitly Spock's) which is shown as amounting to eidetic memory at a glance.

Spock's own words which we must take as logically accurate are that he reads 'somewhat faster' than McCoy. This does not imply any vast superiority.

Somewhat is defined as:

"adverb
to a moderate extent or by a moderate amount; rather.
"matters have improved somewhat since then"
synonyms:   a little, a bit, a little bit, to a limited extent/degree, to a certain degree, to some extent, to some degree, (up) to a point, in some measure, rather, quite, within limits;"

Spock's speed is probably therefore at human limits, not superhuman. Perhaps about that of John Stuart Mill - who lamented that he could not turn the pages of a book fast enough. Spock and any Vulcan would probably have better retention and comprehension at the same speed as a fast-reading human. 1,000 to 2,000 words per minute, equates to 50% comprehension in fast reading humans. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_reading

Comment: This doesn't solidly answer the question. Can you find more sources to back up your claims?